# Function to calculate multiple running totals

Tags: python, function, variables

I have a list of tuples

```
 (something1, 500)
 (something1, 200)
 (something1, 300)
 (something2, 200)
 (something2, 600)
 (something2, 400)
```

I have written a function in pySpark to do the calculation to get a result something like this. The function basically needs to sum up the total of the counts that occur

```
 (something1, 1000),
 (something2, 1200)
```

My function so far

```
             def add_function(key, value):
             last_key = None
             recur_total = 0
             key, value = join_data[0][0], join_data[0][1]
             if last_key == key: 
                 recur_total+ = value
             else:
                if last_key: 
                       recur_total = value
             if last_key == key:
                   recur_total = value
                last_key = key
              if last_key == key:
                   return(last_key, value)
```

Problems I am facing

1. I am unable to paste the function as one function at the pySpark console. It gets split to multiple prompts.
2. It says syntax error at line 6 (recur_total+ = value).

What am I doing wrong and how to rectify this?

Comment: As long as your indentation is correct, the "multiple prompts" do create a single function correctly

Comment: Double check the spacing on the line that gives the syntax error

Comment: The last if statement appears to be spaced inwards by too much.

Comment: I have created this function in a notepad and each line starts right in the beginning of the line. So there should be no issue of indentation. The code pasted here has been formatted for readability.

Comment: If you mean Windows notepad, then I would be careful. My understanding is that it is not a very good text editor.

Comment: Regardless of how it got that way, the indentation of the code in your question is incorrect—and it's not obvious how to fix it, especially the last two `if` statements (and the assignment between them). Please [edit] your question and fix this.

Comment: Keep in mind that the appearance of the indentation may be misleading. Notepad uses 8 spaces as the width of a tab. Putting one tab is NOT equivalent to 8 spaces. Every level of indentation must be done with the same characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I am unable to paste the function as one function at the pySpark console. It gets split to multiple prompts.

I do not understand what you mean by this. As long as your indentation is correct, the "multiple prompts" do create a single function correctly.

> 2. It says syntax error at line 6 (recur_total+ = value).

This error means that you seem to be pasting your code correctly. To fix the error, double check the spacing on the line that gives the syntax error.

Comment: I have created this function in a notepad and each line starts right in the beginning of the line. So there should be no issue of indentation. The code pasted here has been formatted for readability

Comment: @Raghu in python, indentation is important. You must indent correctly in notepad for your code to work. I suggest downloading a text editor made for programming like Notepad++, Sublime Text 3, or Atom.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out answers to your questions regarding proper indentation , but my 2 cents regarding whole function itself..

Task you want to achieve can be simply done using `groupby` of  `itertools`

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [ ('something1', 500),
 ('something1', 200),
 ('something1', 300),
 ('something2', 200),
 ('something2', 600),
 ('something2', 400)]


for key, group in groupby(data, lambda x: x[0]):
      result = 0
      for things in group:
          result = result + things[1]
      print(key,result)
```

Comment: Why not just run sum on each group instead of reinventing the wheel? +1 for introducing groupby either way.

Comment: @Mad Physicist like how?

Comment: Replace the entire inner loop with `result = sum(x[1] for x in group)`

Comment: I am running this function on pySpark console. So probably would not be able to import.

Comment: @Raghu `itertools` is inbuilt module in python. It doesnt matter if you are running stand alone application or running code in pyspark CLI, you should be able to use it. Also @Mad Physicist, I thought you were referencing `reduce`

Comment: I did that and I get the following error. "PipeLinedRDD object is not iterable". The dataset is actually an inmemory join of two datasets. The for mat of data is like this                                                                                      
                        [(u'something1', u'500'),
                         (u'something1', u'200'),
                         (u'something1', u'300'),
                         (u'something2', u'200'),
                         (u'something2', u'600'),
                         (u'something2', u'400')]